# Why doesn't the reverse function I defined execute properly?

Tags: arrays, c, reverse, function-definition

Why doesn't the `renverser` function (reverse) do the job and why does the program exit right after intitialising the table?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void renverser(int t[])
{   int j,i,n;
    for(i=0,j=n-1;i<j;i++,j--)
    {
        int a=t[i];
        t[i]=t[j];
        t[i]=a;
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",t[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{   int i,n;
    float t[100];
    printf("donner le taille du tableau a renverser \n :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   printf("donner l'element %d: \n",i);
        scanf("%d",&t[i]);
    }
    renverser(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(i=0,j=n-1;i<j;i++,j--)` - because `n` has no defined value at that point in time. The `n` in `renverser` is not the same `n` in `main`. You need to get rid of the one in `renverser` and pass it as an additional argument to your function from `main` instead.

Comment: Debugging is a critical skill to develop as you learn how to code. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips to help you get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function does not make a sense because the size of the passed array is unknown.

Moreover the function has undefined behavior because there is used uninitialized variable `n`.

And the type of the function parameter is `int *` while the passed argument expression has the type `float *`.

It seems you mean the following array declaration

```
int t[100];
```

And the function should do only one thing: reverse an array.

The result array you should output in main.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
void renverser( int t[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        int tmp = t[i];
        t[i] = t[n - i - 1];
        t[n - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

and the function can be called like

```
renverser( t, n );
```